# Readd App Part After Re-deploying Sharepoint Hosted Application Using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013

I am building a Sharepoint 2013 application in Visual Studio and deploying to my Sharepoint site via Visual Studio.

Each time I do this the app part is removed from the page and I have to re-add it.

This is obviously not ideal - can anyone advise if there is an application setting / Sharepoint setting for the application to avoid this.

Thanks
Nigel

Answer (score 0):

When we re deploy solution, the previous solution is retracted. Because of this the APP gets uninstalled from the farm. This basically removes all references of the app from the server. This approach is clean.

Now during the next install (re deployment) SharePoint has no clue about the previous references and hence its not possible out of the box.

What you can do is, create a feature receiver to add a page and app part into that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try isolating the behavior into something you can test in the full page experience then switch to the app part when you have everything worked out. You should be able to theoretically add an app part to a page using some code from the app web (it is after all just a carefully crafted IFrame) but you really shouldn't need to.

If you want to look into how to provision an app part into a page, the closest example I've ever seen is provisioning a web part onto a page, and you can find a couple nice examples in the [OfficeDev/PnP GitHub Repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP) for that, like this one: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/bbc4cb6da128cad01bb00cd6f61011ab38db556a/Samples/Core.UploadWebPart/Core.UploadWebPartWeb/Pages/Default.aspx.cs

Definitely be aware that app parts are different than web parts, but this should give you an idea of how you manipulate a web page on the host web from code in the app web.

Answer (score 0):

When You make an App part and follow all the steps click on Save button which is on the right hand corner on top which will save your current settings on your PC as admin and end user it will not get removed.

Regards
Basant Gera